# Django - redefine Form Select using pk URL

Tags: django, forms, url, select, init

I need to set input (select) value using pk sended by URL.

Using `__init__` in form, almost get the answer, but `__init__` method is executed twice and clean my value.

Form:

```
class CrearDelitoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Delito
        exclude = ()

    def __init__(self, numero_pk = None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CrearDelitoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["imputado"].queryset = Imputado.objects.filter(numero_id = numero_pk)

DelitoFormset = inlineformset_factory(
    Expediente,
    Delito,
    form=CrearDelitoForm,    
    extra=1,
    can_delete=True,
    fields=('imputado', 'delito', 'categoria'),
    } 
)
```

Views:

```
class CrearDelito(CreateView):
    model = Delito
    form_class = CrearDelitoForm
    template_name = 'crear_delito.html'

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['formset'] = DelitoFormset()        
        context['expedientes'] = Expediente.objects.filter(id = self.kwargs['pk'])
        return context

    def get_form_kwargs(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['numero_pk'] = self.kwargs['pk']
        return kwargs
```

**
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
June 08, 2020 - 11:33:57
Django version 2.2.12, using settings 'red.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
, ]>

**

I think problem is on   **context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)** but don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `CreateView` makes a form, the form you specified in the `form_class`. It will furthermore pass the `request.POST` and `request.FILES` to the form, you thus do *not* have to construct a formset yourself, but let the `CreateView` do that.

You need to pass the dictionary to the `form_kwargs` to the `form_kwargs` of the formset, so the `get_form_kwargs` needs to be altered to:

```
class CrearDelito(CreateView):
    model = Delito
    form_class = DelitoFormset
    template_name = 'crear_delito.html'

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['expedientes'] = Expediente.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        context['formset'] = context['form']
        return context

    def get_form_kwargs(self, **kwargs):
        form_kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs(**kwargs)
        form_kwargs['form_kwargs'] = {'numero_pk': self.kwargs['pk']}
        form_kwargs['instance'] = Expediente.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return form_kwargs

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('repositorio:crear_victima', args=[request.POST.get('numero_id')])
```

Comment: It works, but still don't show imputados(accused)'s choices. I have 3 models: Delito(crime), imputados(accused) and expediente(file).  After load file information, system require imputados(accused). After that, I need  each accused obtain all crimes cometed. I do that using formset and creating form dinamically. So template receive expediente pk (file pk). Whit this file pk I need to show only imputados(accused) from that file. Using this solution it's missing queryset developed in forms for imputados(accused). I newbie in Django, so apologize for my mistakes..

Comment: @MarceIaco: normally that is passed through `['form_kwargs'] = {'numero_pk': self.kwargs['pk']}`. I made however a small typo: it should return `form_kwargs`, can you try the edited version?

Comment: Chapeau!! It's works!
My sincere thanks and admiration for your knowledge.

Comment: I have a new problem. Finally form result invalid... "Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices" I thinks it's about imputado pk (accused). But if I compare the previous working script, it show the same values... **('delito_set-TOTAL_FORMS', '1')('delito_set-INITIAL_FORMS', '0')('delito_set-MIN_NUM_FORMS', '0')('delito_set-MAX_NUM_FORMS', '1000')('delito_set-0-id', '')('delito_set-0-numero', '')('delito_set-0-imputado', '12')('delito_set-0-delito', '43')('delito_set-0-categoria', 'Principal')('delito_set-0-DELETE', '')** .

Comment: Working script result: **('delito_set-TOTAL_FORMS', '1')('delito_set-INITIAL_FORMS', '0')('delito_set-MIN_NUM_FORMS', '0')('delito_set-MAX_NUM_FORMS', '1000')('delito_set-0-id', '')('delito_set-0-numero', '')('delito_set-0-imputado', '12')('delito_set-0-delito', '43')('delito_set-0-categoria', 'Principal')('delito_set-0-DELETE', '')**

Comment: @MarceIaco: do you make the POST request to the same view, and with the *same* value for `pk`?

Comment: It's my post: `def post (self, request, * args, ** kwargs):
        expediente = Expediente.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        form = DelitoFormset(request.POST, instance=expediente)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
                return redirect('repositorio:crear_victima', request.POST.get('numero_id'))
        else:
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'formset': form, 'mensaje':'Ocurrió un error. Contáctese con el administrador.'})`

Comment: !MarceIaco: but you do not need to define a `post`. The `createView` will handle this as well.

Comment: Yes, I was using this to redirect form after post depending on one value in template where I save the origin. I have try taking off this part, and error is still the same.

Comment: It's the model:  `numero = models.ForeignKey(Expediente, on_delete=models.CASCADE,  blank = False)
    delito = models.ForeignKey(CatalogoDelitos, on_delete=models.CASCADE,  blank = False)
    imputado = models.ForeignKey(Imputado, on_delete=models.CASCADE,  blank = False)
    categoria = models.CharField('Categoria', max_length = 20, blank = False, choices = CATDEL_CHOICES)
    situacion = models.BooleanField('Delito Activado/Delito no activado', default = True)`

Comment: @MarceIaco: but you specify where to redirect with `success_url` (or `get_success_url`). So here you override `get_success_url`, and return `reverse('repositorio:crear_victima', args=[request.POST.get('numero_id')])`

Comment: Yes, my mistake, I'm trying to solve that now. But, still persist the problem. How should I pass numero(file) in the form, taking pk value and as a hidden field? Numero(file) is the field used on url (pk).

Comment: @MarceIaco: you simply add the instance to the `form_kwargs`.

Comment: Printing result I get: ``{'initial': {}, 'prefix': None, 'instance': None, 'form_kwargs': {'numero_pk': 12}}`` Trying: ``form_kwargs['instance'] = self.kwargs['pk'] `` get: ``'int' object has no attribute 'pk'`` Sorry, I know it's basic question.

Comment: Working on the issue I have realiced the problem is not in instance asignation. Is with imputado's value: **[{'imputado': ['Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.']}]** Do you know why this happend.